# What is the collective name for the evolution chamber, forge, and engineering bay?

Tags: starcraft-2, terminology, starcraft

Zerg's evolution chamber, Protoss' forge, and Terran's engineering bay have similar roles. All are pre-requisites for anti-air and detection buildings for the respective races.

What collective term or phrase could be used for these three structures?

Example scenario: You are playing a team game (with some inexperienced friends) and you spot a Twilight Council in production (implying the need for detection). Instead of saying "guys, better start building your evo chamber, forge, or e-bay", I would like to shorten it to something like "guys, better start building your  ***insert collective name here***."

Comment: "Basic upgrades"?

Comment: Tier 1 upgrade building (TUB).

Comment: @ayckoster if this is not true it should be.

Comment: Sorry I meant it as a suggestion otherwise I would have posted an answer :)

Comment: Seems like a combination of dbmerlin 's and decency 's answers (perhaps with @ayckoster 's suggestion) could be great answer.

Answer (score 12):

There is no collective term for those structures. In discussions people usually refer either directly to the upgrades instead of the buildings - i.e. "Start working on your upgrades" instead of "Get an evolution chamber/..." - or the function the building is required for - i.e. "Get detection" or "Get static defenses".

Suggesting names is outside the scope of this platform, so i won't suggest any new term. It is not required anyways.

Answer (score 5):

Upgrade facility. I don't have a source other than watching way too many VOD's of SC:BW and SC2.

It's not a universal term by any means but it's used occasionally.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such name and there will not be. I tried to introduce this problem to Teamliquid in this [post](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=337307).

Well, it seems that the community does not want new therms / names. They suggest using "upgrades", +X, +X/+X or calling them by their names (EBay, Forge, Evo). As long as no one "famous", like Day[9], Artosis or Tasteless support the new name it will not be accepted. But even this is not certain.

It will be almost the same as Husky's Destiny Cloud Fist build. It was first known as the 111 (One One One) build, but the name seemed somewhat stupid so he tried to introduce a new name. Till now he still uses Destiny Cloud Fist on his channel, but the community still calls it 111 build.

But if you think there should be a collective name, by all means try to use it as often as you can. Perhaps it will crawl its way in.